# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Could not convert string to DateTime: "-0001-11-30T00:00:00-0500"

Tags: c#, json

I'm using the [Marvel developer's API](https://developer.marvel.com/) and some of the data is returned as a date in this format, and when trying to deserialize into DateTime in C# I get this exception:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Could not convert string to DateTime: "-0001-11-30T00:00:00-0500"
```

I tried making DateTime nullable but is not working. Any ideas of how to solve it?

EDIT: This is my c#class and the .json and I want to deserialize

```
public class ComicDataWrapper
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Copyright { get; set; }
    public string AttributionText { get; set; }
    public string AttributionHTML { get; set; }
    public ComicDataContainer Data { get; set; }
    public string Etag { get; set; }
}

public class ComicDataContainer
{
    public int Offset { get; set; }
    public int Limit { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Comic> Results { get; set; }
}

public class Comic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DigitalId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double IssueNumber { get; set; }
    public string VariantDescription { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime ? Modified { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string UPC { get; set; }
    public string DiamondCode { get; set; }
    public string EAN { get; set; }
    public string ISSN { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public TextObject[] TextObjects { get; set; }
    public string ResourceURI { get; set; }
    public Url[] Urls { get; set; }
    public SeriesSummary Series { get; set; }
    public ComicSummary[] Variants { get; set; }
    public ComicSummary[] Collections { get; set; }
    public ComicSummary[] CollectedIssues { get; set; }
    public ComicDate[] Dates { get; set; }
    public ComicPrice[] Prices { get; set; }
    public Image Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public Image[] Images { get; set; }
    public CreatorList Creators { get; set; }
    public CharacterList Characters { get; set; }
    public StoryList Stories { get; set; }
    public EventList Events { get; set; }
}

public class TextObject
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Url
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
}

public class SeriesSummary
{
    public string ResourceURI { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ComicSummary
{
    public string ResourceURI { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ComicDate
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}

public class ComicPrice
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
}

public class CreatorList
{
    public int Available { get; set; }
    public int Returned { get; set; }
    public string CollectionURI { get; set; }
    public CreatorSummary[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class CreatorSummary
{
    public string ResourceURI { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}

public class CharacterList
{
    public int Available { get; set; }
    public int Returned { get; set; }
    public string CollectionURI { get; set; }
    public CharacterSummary[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class CharacterSummary
{
    public string ResourceURI { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}

public class StoryList
{
    public int Available { get; set; }
    public int Returned { get; set; }
    public string CollectionURI { get; set; }
    public StorySummary[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class StorySummary
{
    public string ResourceURI { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class EventList
{
    public int Available { get; set; }
    public int Returned { get; set; }
    public string CollectionURI { get; set; }
    public EventSummary[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class EventSummary
{
    public string ResourceURI { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

{
```

"code": "int",
"status": "string",
"copyright": "string",
"attributionText": "string",
"attributionHTML": "string",
"data": {
"offset": "int",
"limit": "int",
"total": "int",
"count": "int",
"results": [
{
"id": "int",
"digitalId": "int",
"title": "string",
"issueNumber": "double",
"variantDescription": "string",
"description": "string",
"modified": "Date",
"isbn": "string",
"upc": "string",
"diamondCode": "string",
"ean": "string",
"issn": "string",
"format": "string",
"pageCount": "int",
"textObjects": [
{
"type": "string",
"language": "string",
"text": "string"
}
],
"resourceURI": "string",
"urls": [
{
"type": "string",
"url": "string"
}
],
"series": {
"resourceURI": "string",
"name": "string"
},
"variants": [
{
"resourceURI": "string",
"name": "string"
}
],
"collections": [
{
"resourceURI": "string",
"name": "string"
}
],
"collectedIssues": [
{
"resourceURI": "string",
"name": "string"
}
],
"dates": [
{
"type": "string",
"date": "Date"
}
],
"prices": [
{
"type": "string",
"price": "float"
}
],
"thumbnail": {
"path": "string",
"extension": "string"
},
"images": [
{
"path": "string",
"extension": "string"
}
],
"creators": {
"available": "int",
"returned": "int",
"collectionURI": "string",
"items": [
{
"resourceURI": "string",
"name": "string",
"role": "string"
}
]
},
"characters": {
"available": "int",
"returned": "int",
"collectionURI": "string",
"items": [
{
"resourceURI": "string",
"name": "string",
"role": "string"
}
]
},
"stories": {
"available": "int",
"returned": "int",
"collectionURI": "string",
"items": [
{
"resourceURI": "string",
"name": "string",
"type": "string"
}
]
},
"events": {
"available": "int",
"returned": "int",
"collectionURI": "string",
"items": [
{
"resourceURI": "string",
"name": "string"
}
]
}
}
]
},
"etag": "string"
}

Comment: That's exciting. Looks like someone tried to return "0001-01-01T00:00:00" (which is the earliest date that `DateTime` can represent), but got caught out by timezones. You might have to do some custom deserialization, and manually check for that leading `-`

Comment: @canton7 Why november then ? It should be december the 31st right ?

Comment: True, I missed that

Comment: You should use `DateTime.Parse(string)` to convert string to DateTime.

Comment: It seems to me that  you will need a custom json converter. To help you you have to post an example of json string and the c# class you are trying to deserilalize to.

Comment: @Serge I edited my question and added both .json and c# class

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see any real data in a json string, and your classes don't have any DateTime properties. What code do you use to serialize and what property do you have a problem with?

Comment: I added [JsonIgnore] (to ignore the error for now) to the "DateTime? Modified" property from the "Comic" class , this is the property giving me problems, since on the .json returned by the API it is "-0001-11-30T00:00:00-0500" for most values...

Comment: Possible workaround : in the json-string replace that date with a correct DateTime. MinValue, just before you deserialize